# Systrace not generating html report or collecting output, exception getting results from atrace

Tags: android, systrace

I have recently started to research `systrace`, but have not succeded in running a trace that produces an html report as it should. I have tried tracing on two different units:

Samsung Galaxy A3 - Android 7.0

Samsung Xcover 3 - Android 5.1

The traceback produced from `systrace` is identical i both cases, screenshot below.

[image]

It seems like there is a timeout after trace is completed and the thread that `systrace` is running on gets blocked. Anyone familiar with this problem?